# A comparison between "as long as" and "while"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Please imagine a father is polishing his young son who has committed a very bad action. He is going to throw him out of the house while he changes. Which one of the following self made structures do not sound idiomatic:

> - Don’t return to this house **as long as** you have **not changed** yourself.
> - Don’t return to this house **as long as** you have **changed** yourself.
> - Don’t return to this house **while** you have **not changed** yourself.
> - Don’t return to this house **while** you have **changed** yourself.

Comment: You cannot use "while" here. Also you cannot use "as long as" in the second one (when you are not using "not"). You should instead use "until" to stress the duration, and "unless" to stress the condition. Aside from that, "yourself" is already implied and therefore useless in those sentences. If one had to change not oneself but something else, even part of oneself, then that something should be added (changed = changed (yourself), changed one's haircut, changed one's attitude etc.).

Comment: do you mean *punishing his young son*? Morgan FR is correct. The sentences are awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these are idiomatic. Instead you want to use *until*, "Don't come back until ...".  Examples:

> Don't come back until you have *learned your lesson*.
>
> Don't come back until you have *changed your ways*.
>
> Don't return until you understand how you have disappointed your mother.

and so on.